# C# Newton deserialize JSON with sub lists

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Let's say that this is the API [json](/questions/tagged/json)response from Facebook (at the end).

Until now i am deserializing the newton [json](/questions/tagged/json)getting the id and `created_time` for each one, but the second one includes reactions which is a list and a comments element which is another list.

I am using the following to loop through posts:

```
var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookPostData>(fbData);
```

And the

```
for each post in posts.... 
id = post.id
```

How inside the loop that i am could loop to the post `Reactions` and post `Comments`.

The class that i have so far and working  is:

```
public class FacebookPostData
{
    public List<FacebookPost> Data { get; set; }
}    

public class FacebookPost
{        
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
}
```

The API response is:

```
{
  "data": [{
      "id": "",
      "created_time": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "",
      "created_time": "",
      "reactions": {
        "data": [{
            "id": "",
            "name": "",
            "type": ""
          },
          {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",
            "type": ""
          }
        ],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "",
            "after": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "comments": {
        "data": [{
          "created_time": "",
          "from": {
            "name": "",
            "id": ""
          },
          "message": "",
          "id": ""
        }],
        "paging": {
          "cursors": {
            "before": "",
            "after": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "",
    "next": ""
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your classes could be structured in this way:

```
public class FacebookPostData
{
    public List<FacebookPost> data { get; set; }
    public Paging3 paging { get; set; }
    public FacebookPostData()
    {
        this.data = new List<FacebookPost>();
        this.paging = new Paging3();
    }
}

public class FacebookPost
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public Reactions reactions { get; set; }
    public Comments comments { get; set; }
    public FacebookPost()
    {
        this.reactions = new Reactions();
        this.comments = new Comments();
    }
}

public class Paging3
{
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
}

public class Reactions
{
    public List<Data2> data { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
    public Reactions()
    {
        this.data = new List<Data2>();
        this.paging = new Paging();
    }
}

public class Data2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
    public Paging()
    {
        this.cursors = new Cursors();
    }
}

public class Cursors
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    public List<Data3> data { get; set; }
    public Paging2 paging { get; set; }
    public Comments()
    {
        this.data = new List<Data3>();
        this.paging = new Paging2();
    }
}

public class Data3
{
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Data3()
    {
        this.from = new From();
    }
}

public class Paging2
{
    public Cursors2 cursors { get; set; }
    public Paging2()
    {
        this.cursors = new Cursors2(); 
    }
}

public class From
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors2
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}
```

So, you can do something like this:

```
var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookPostData>(fbData);
foreach(var post in posts.data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(post.id);

    // Reactions...
    foreach(var reaction in post.reactions.data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reaction.id);
    }
    // Comments...
    foreach(var comment in post.comments.data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(comment.id);
        Console.WriteLine(comment.from.id);
        Console.WriteLine(comment.from.name);
    }
}
```

See this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PkhckS).

Hope this helps.